# TinyMCE override font style menu items

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tinymce

We use TinyMCE as in-place editors to let user live edit contents. However, when using a dark background with light text, TinyMCE uses this text colour instead of using black.

[image: sample demo of dark background]

*(**Note:** please ignore the theme colours, this is only for demo purposes.)*

How can the font styles menu use black font colour instead of the one defined in the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `preview_styles` configuration option for TinyMCE:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/user-formatting-options/#preview_styles

You can stop any/all types of previews with

```
preview_styles: false
```

...or you can control what parts of it to preview with a string such as:

```
preview_styles: 'font-size font-weight'
```

The default for this value in TinyMCE 6 is:

```
font-family font-size font-weight font-style text-decoration text-transform color background-color border border-radius outline text-shadow
```

so you can use any subset of those values if you opt to pass a string.

Comment: Thank you! This was easier than expected!